# observe scroll view's 'dragging' property but received no notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, key-value-observing, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a custom `UIView` that is added to as a `subView` of a `UIScrollView`, and I want that `UIView` automatically repositioned whenever the `UIScrollView` scrolls. In addition to observe the `UIScrollView's` `contentOffset` property(which works fine), I also need observes its `dragging` property:

```
[scrollView addObserver:self 
             forKeyPath:@"dragging" 
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                context:NULL];
```

but in the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` method, I didn't receive any `NSNotification` for the change of the `dragging` property, what's the problem here? Thanks.

### updated

Since i'm gonna reuse this custom `UIView` in multiple `UIViewControllers`, I want the custom view itself handles the repositioning logic, rather than duplicate the repositioning logic in each `UIViewController's` `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods(like `scrollViewDidScroll` thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIKit is not KVO-compliant in general. The fact that some properties may generate change notifications isn't reliable - it's not documented and may change in future versions etc.

Since you need to reuse this reposition logic, why not separate it properly? Btw - you can place it in your custom view class itself.

Comment: Thanks. I find another way around which does not involve observing the `dragging` property anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Or you set a delegate to you UIScrollView and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`

Comment: Since i'm gonna reuse this custom view in multiple view controllers, I want the custom view itself handles the repositioning logic, rather than duplicate the repositioning logic in each view controller's UIScrollViewDelegate methods(like scrollViewDidScroll thing).

Comment: Try to override the layoutSubviews method in your class, this method is called when a view has to layout its subviews.